# LCD display connected on LVDS not working

Tags: xorg

I'm trying to run Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a Intel N2600 Board with a 7" LCD panel connected through LVDS connector.
I successfully installed Ubuntu Server and I have installed also xorg and openbox (beacause I need a graphic environment).

The board I'm using has a VGA output (where I have connected a monitor to perform the installation) and the LVDS connectors (where I have plugged the 7" LCD panel).
When grub starts the OS, I initially see the kernel messages on the 7" LCD display, then it goes blank and there's no way to make it work, while the VGA output instead works correctly.

Using xrandr -q gives me this output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-0 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm
   1440x900       59.9*+   75.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-0 connected primary 800x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   800x480        60.0*+   50.0     40.0
```

It seems that the panel is recognized (eDP-0), but I'm not able to run the X graphical environment on it. 
I tried to run

```
xrandr --output eDP-0 --primary
```

but nothing happens.
How can I switch the output on the eDP-0 display?